# Can we save QwtPlot for everytime step as images?

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to visualize camera images and joint angles in matlab. Camera images are fine. For plotting the joint angles with respect to time, I am trying to save QwtPlot as image at everytime stamp collected and then load them as matlab plot.

Can you give me any idea on how to do it?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257150/can-we-save-qwtplot-for-everytime-step-as-images?/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2017-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should save the joint angles into a rosbag http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#record then load the bag into matlab https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/rosbag.html .

If you really want to save the QwtPlot as an image you could screen grab it into a ros image with https://github.com/lucasw/screen_grab but the underlying plot data would not be easily recoverable for usage any other tool, it would just be a series of images.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on 2017-03-16**:
Thank you!  I have matlab 2015b, so  I don't think I will be able to load rosbag in there. My idea is to save images and then stream them inmatlab plot().
I tried screen_grab, but it is not working for me(ros indigo). `Failed to load nodelet [/screen_grab] of type [screen_grab/ScreenGrab]`

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-03-16**:
It's pretty easy to convert rosbags into csv files, which are simple to load in matlab- and maybe there is a python script to convert to mat?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-03-16**:
I haven't touched screengrab in a while so I'll have to try it out- but you would have to do machine vision on the plot image to get plot data out of them, which seems much more difficult than any other approach.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-03-16**:
If you want to sort out what is wrong with screengrab go ahead and make an issue on https://github.com/lucasw/screen_grab/issues and cut and paste the command you ran and the complete output.